# Is there any way to hire someone to generate a sufficiently small hash of a value + nonce, without knowing value nor nonce?

Tags: hash, multiparty-computation

Suppose I have a 128-bit value `X`, and I want a `keccak_256(X || nonce)` sufficiently small to require a lot of work. Is there any simple/obvious way (possibly interactive) way to hire someone to find me such a nonce, in a way that he doesn't learn about `X`, and that he doesn't even know what `nonce` he produced?

I can't fit that particular problem on what zkSnarks seem to enable one to do.

Comment: Basically any MPC system would work.  I bet you could code something up in SPDZ in a couple days.   Or perhaps JustGarble has a keccak_256 implementation already.

Comment: Is there a strict requirement for 256bit keccak as hash function, or could you use e.g. sha256 instead?

Comment: Well, you could hire him to find a `Y` in the range $[2^{128}, 2^{129}-1]$ with a sufficiently small `keccak_256(Y)`; he gives you `Y`, and you compute `nonce = Y-X`.  He then gets no information about `X`, and he doesn't know what  `nonce` he produced...

Comment: Can you clarify what "X + nonce" means in your question? Do you mean arithmetic addition or bit string concatination?

Comment: @raisyn sorry for the delay and unusual notation. I mean string concatenation. I think I'd rather use Keccak for Ethereum interoperability, but if there is a solution using SHA256 there should be one for Keccak...?

Comment: @poncho see above, I'm sorry :(

Comment: If it's string concatination, here's the obvious solution: with X, you select a random value N1 (256 bytes long for keccak_256, 48 bytes for SHA-256), and compute the intermediate hash state of the partial hash of X || N1.  You give this intermediate hash state to your hireling, who finds an N2 such that Hash(X || N1|| N2) is a small value, and sends it back to you.  This gives you the value nonce = N1 || N2 you're looking for, and he cannot sure this partial state to backtrack to X, and he doesn't know the full value of none (as he doesn't know N1).

Comment: @poncho not sure I get it... once he has a partial hash of `Hash(X || N1)`, how he will proceed to complete the hash `Hash(X || N1 || N2)`? That later hash, at this point, would have a completely different partial state from the former. He would need to be able to revert it and start all over again starting with `X || N1 || N2`, but that would be useless, obviously.

Comment: @MaiaVictor: both Keccak and SHA-256 work by splitting up the message into blocks; then they start with an initial state (the 'IV' in the case of SHA-256), and have a function that takes the current state and the next message block, and gives a next state (that's not how Keccak is usually described, but it could be expressed that way).  So, what we're looking at is the state after the hash function processes the blocks that form `X || N1`; the hash function is a function of that state (and nothing else about `X || N1` (except it's length in the case of SHA-256)

Comment: Oh, I get what you mean now, d'oh! That obviously works, thank you @poncho

Comment: Hmm, I wonder if it is possible to generate a nonce of exactly 128 bits without revealing any of those bits to the hireling.

Comment: This is very interesting. @poncho, if you could write a self contained answer, it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's the obvious answer that avoids multiparty computation (which tends to be expensive):

- Given your $X$, select a random value $N1$, which would be 256 bytes long for keccak_256 and 48 bytes long for SHA-256, and compute the intermediate hash state of $Hash(X || N1)$.

  - If your hash function is SHA-256, this is an intermediate hash of 64 bytes (1 SHA-256 block), which requires a single hash compression function evaluation (yielding a 256 bit intermediate state)
  - If your hash function is keccak_256, this is an intermediate hash of 272 bytes (2 Keccak-256 blocks), which requires two permutation evaluations (yielding a 1600 bit intermediate state).  We use two permutations for Keccak because the permutation function is invertible, and so if we used only a single block, the hireling could invert the permutation and recover $X$ and $N1$
- We give the intermediate hash state to your hireling, who searches fir an N2 such that Hash(X || N1|| N2) is a small value; he can do this because both hash functions can be expressed as functions of the intermediate state and the rest of the message.
- Once he has found such an N2, he sends it back to you. This gives you the value $nonce = N1 || N2$ you're looking for.

This solves the issue; the hireling cannot convert the hash state back into $X$, and since he does not know the value of $N1$, he doesn't know the full value of none.